# How to import data from sybase table to Cassandra table using sqoop

Tags: cassandra

I am unable to import data using sqoop from sybase table into Cassandra table. The data is getting read from sybase and staged into hdfs but not getting into the Cassandra.

Please help...

Comment: Can you give the command line you are using to do this please and the versions of software you are using.

Comment: I used the command given on datestax website on importing data from MySQL to Cassandra, I used the sybase connect string instead of MySQL and used --drives parameter to define which sybase driver I need to use.

Comment: Driver used was jtds sybase driver

Comment: any help in my query??

Comment: any help with giving me the exact command line you using and versions of software you are using???

Comment: dse sqoop cql-import \
--verbose \
--driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver \
 --connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:<hostname>:29812/andy_test \
      --username sa569028 \
      --password sa569028 \
      --table sybasedeep \
      --cassandra-keyspace npa_nxx \
      --cassandra-table casspoc \
   --cassandra-host  <CASS-host>\
   --cassandra-port 9042 \
      --cassandra-column-mapping id:id,code:code \
      --split-by id -m 1 \
   --target-dir file:////tmp/sybasedeep1

Comment: I used the above command to import data using datax-cassandra from sybase to cassandra, but seems the data is coming in Filesystem but in reflecting in cassandra tables, i am not receiving any errors. job completes sucessfully. Using the same command and replacing with required mysql parameters the data is getting imported in cassandra table but this is not the case with sybase. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (identified in the comments) is with the use of the `--driver` parameter in the sqoop options. If you use the `--driver` option then you must also include the

```
--connection-manager com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.DseConnectionManager
```

option. This was introduced in DSE versions 4.7.4 and 4.8.1 to fix the problem of imports not working for databases not specifically supported by sqoop.

Comment: Thanks for help, i shall try this and see if this works.

Comment: I have tested the same and able to sucessfully import the data from sybase to cassandra.

Comment: dse sqoop cql-import \ --verbose \ --driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver \  --connect jdbc:jtds:sybase://<HOSTNAME>:29812/<DBNAME> \  --connection-manager com.datastax.bdp.sqoop.DseConnectionManager \ --username <USERNAME> \ --password <PASSWORD> \ --table <TABNAME> \ --cassandra-keyspace <KSNAME> \
--cassandra-table <CASS TABLE> \   --cassandra-host  127.0.0.1 \   --cassandra-port 9042 \      --cassandra-column-mapping id:id,code:code \      --split-by id -m 1 \ --target-dir file:////tmp/sybased808

Comment: I am able to load the data , thanks for help. but I am getting this warning:

Comment: WARN  05:44:46 Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, but epoll is not available. Using NIO instead.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll242558397880477518.so: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll242558397880477518.so)
WARN  05:44:50 Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Comment: any help is appreciated to resolve the able warning.